# Add-Migration while there are explicit migrations pending

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So I have a basic problem trying to generate a migration when I don't have a DB in sync (up to the latest migration, in fact, have no DB at all) and have already made substantial changes to my model.

This are the specific details:

1. Have a sequence of explicit migrations.
2. Have no database. In short, have lots of pending changes.
3. Made changes to the models/context.
4. When trying to Add-Migration, it will complain saying precisely that **explicit migrations are pending**.
5. If I try to execute the migration (and bring my DB in sync), either via Update-Database or migrate.exe, it will fail (after applying explicit migrations successfully), **and automatic migrations are not enabled.**
6. **I don't want to enable automatic migrations either** (to prevent any schema changes to be committed and go unaccounted in code.)

I realize that after the failure in #5 I can now run #4. Then re-try #5 and voilá.

My Question is if this is the expected approach to solve this silly situation.

Comment: If you have no DB currently, you can just delete the migrations folder and call `dbCtx.Database.Delete()` to start the whole thing fresh from your models.

Comment: How did you get multiple migrations without a database?

Comment: @Dismissile: We are a team of _N_ devs and some of us have local DBs that are behind latest migrations, As I described above, the dev gets latest code and starts to make model changes without having run pending migrations; that's a typical scenario. Another one is if the dev has never even worked on the project and now gets all the code for the first time.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I'm afraid that is not a feasible approach — this is not a personal project: it's a team project AND it's already been releases to several environments at different versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use the following approach.

**First you need to apply migrations and specify the last one.**

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration AnyMigrationName

# It updates database to a migration named "AnyMigrationName"
# This will apply migrations if the target hasn't been applied or roll back migrations
# if it has
```

**When your local database is updated you simply add new migration.**

```
PM> Add-Migration NewMigrationName

# it scaffolds a new migration named "NewMigrationName"
```

Looking for a good reference I found these blog posts about [EF Migrations](http://coding.abel.nu/series/ef-migrations/) that can help you a lot. They cover many questions and [EF Migrations and a Merge Conflict](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/ef-migrations-and-a-merge-conflict/) and [EF Migrations Command Reference](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Add-Migration) in particular.

Comment: Had the same problem, turned out my new migration wasn't added to source control. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

this error is shown when you have many Migrations pending.

> If you don't need  existing migrations, first delete (exclude) all
>   migration on Migration folder and then add a new migration.

`Add-Migration new`